# Refresh conent with JQuery/AJAX after using a MVC partial view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, partial-views

Using the following JQuery/AJAX function I'm calling a partial view when an option is changed in a combobox named "ReportedIssue" that is also in the partial view.  The  is named "tableContent".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#ReportedIssue')
      .change(function() {
          var styleValue = $(this).val();
          $('#tableContent').load(
          '/CurReport/TableResults',
          { style: styleValue }
        );
      })
      .change();
    });
</script>
```

My problem is that after the jump to the partial view I lose the link to the javascript.  I think I'm supposed to use the JQuery ".live()" but I'm unsure.

In short, I want to re-establish the link between my JavaScript and my combobox and  after the inclusion of the partial view's HTML.

I hope I'm being clear enough,

Aaron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is **deprecated**, see [Mike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11252585/2679437)

---

As of jQuery 1.4 you can use the [live](http://api.jquery.com/live) handler with the change event.  Simply change your code to work with it.  If you are stuck with an earlier version of jQuery, you need to reapply the handler in the AJAX callback.

```
$(function() { 
    $('#ReportedIssue').live('change', function() { 
      var styleValue = $(this).val(); 
      $('#tableContent').load( 
          '/CurReport/TableResults', 
           { style: styleValue } 
      ); 
    })
});
```

Comment: Thank you!  I was doing something sorta like this but I couldn't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 2):

Since .live() is now deprecated. Use .on(). Or, in my success callback, I simply did a .load()
`$('#container').load('index.php', '#right');` Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should use live():

```
$('#ReportedIssue').live('click', function() {
```